# AWS Grafana Slack notification failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, grafana-alerts

I have a AWS managed service Grafana getting/extracting data from my ec2 instance in same region.

I set up the VPC on grafana now when setting up the slack notification and testing it

it always return 408 but when I remove the VPC set up its working.

VPC setup:

- 3 Subnet
- 1 Route table connected to:
- 1 Internet gateway

This set up should be able to send http connection to slack but it doesn't

Let me know what you think!

Comment: This [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/grafana/latest/userguide/AMG-configure-vpc.html) may help.